# Issue in one page magneto website

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess, magento

I have developed marketplace website using CED extension for marketplace in magento. My website was working fne few days back but now i m facing strange issue in Vendor shop page it showing error rest of website is working fine. 
When i Open the page it shows syntax error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1=1 AND (
>   e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = '1') AND
>   (e.min_price' at line 2

query was:

```
SELECT FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 100) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM `mage_catalog_product_index_price` AS `e` 
INNER JOIN `mage_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` 
   ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' 
  AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4)
  AND cat_index.category_id = '2' 
WHERE 1=1 
  AND (e.entity_id IN('1749', '1750', '1751', '1752', '1753', '1754', '1755', '1756', '1757', '1758', '1759', '1760', '1761', '1762', '1763', '1764', '1765', '1766', '1767', '1768', '1769', '1770', '1771', '1772', '1773', '1774', '1775', '1776', '1777', '1778', '1779', '1780', '1781', '1782', '1783', '1784', '1785', '1786', '1787', '1788', '1789', '1790', '1791', '1792', '1793', '1794', '1795', '1796', '1797', '1798', '1799', '1800', '1801', '1802', '1803', '1804', '1805', '1806', '1807', '1809', '1810', '1811', '1812', '1813', '1814', '1815', '1816', '1817', '1818', '1819', '1820', '1821', '1822', '1824', '1825', '1826', '1827', '1828', '1829', '1830', '1831', '1832', '1833', '1834', '1836', '1837', '1838', '1839', '1840', '1841', '1842', '1843', '1844', '1845', '1846', '1847', '1848', '1849', '1850', '1851', '1852', '1853', '1854', '1855', '1856', '1876', '1877', '1878', '1879', '1880', '1881', '1882', '1892', '1893', '1894', '1895', '1896', '1897', '1898', '1899', '1900', '1901', '1902', '1903', '1904', '1905')) 1=1 
 AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) 
 AND ( e.customer_group_id = '1') 
 AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 100) + 1 
ORDER BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 100) + 1 ASC
```

Can anyone please tell me where the issue would be

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1=1 AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = '1') AND (e.min_price' at line 2, query was: SELECT FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 100) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `mage_catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `mage_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1'

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full details from your comment.

Comment: I try to add screenshot but dont no why its not adding though i add error itself

Answer (score 0):

Remove `1=1` twice (first after `WHERE` and second after `IN` list):

```
SELECT FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 100) + 1 AS range,
       COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM mage_catalog_product_index_price AS e
JOIN mage_catalog_category_product_index AS cat_index 
  ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id
 AND cat_index.store_id='1'
 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4)
 AND cat_index.category_id = '2'
WHERE e.entity_id IN('1749', '1750', '1751', '1752', '1753', '1754', '1755', '1756', '1757', '1758', '1759', '1760', '1761', '1762', '1763', '1764', '1765', '1766', '1767', '1768', '1769', '1770', '1771', '1772', '1773', '1774', '1775', '1776', '1777', '1778', '1779', '1780', '1781', '1782', '1783', '1784', '1785', '1786', '1787', '1788', '1789', '1790', '1791', '1792', '1793', '1794', '1795', '1796', '1797', '1798', '1799', '1800', '1801', '1802', '1803', '1804', '1805', '1806', '1807', '1809', '1810', '1811', '1812', '1813', '1814', '1815', '1816', '1817', '1818', '1819', '1820', '1821', '1822', '1824', '1825', '1826', '1827', '1828', '1829', '1830', '1831', '1832', '1833', '1834', '1836', '1837', '1838', '1839', '1840', '1841', '1842', '1843', '1844', '1845', '1846', '1847', '1848', '1849', '1850', '1851', '1852', '1853', '1854', '1855', '1856', '1876', '1877', '1878', '1879', '1880', '1881', '1882', '1892', '1893', '1894', '1895', '1896', '1897', '1898', '1899', '1900', '1901', '1902', '1903', '1904', '1905')
  AND e.website_id = '1'
  AND e.customer_group_id = '1'
  AND e.min_price IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 100) + 1
ORDER BY range ASC
```